# Problemas no print() de Resultados

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estou a escrever um código que calcula probabilidades com base numa determinada base de dados em Excel.

Ao fazer isto em Excel tenho o resultado final na coluna "Probabilidade3 %":

[image: Resultados]

Agora preciso de fazer o mesmo, mas em Python. Como tal, fiz um código similar ao usado em Excel, o problema é que ao juntar as probabilidades com:

```
matriz=np.array([[R], [R1], [R2], [R5], [R6], [R7]])
```

e posteriormente:

```
Probabilidades=np.max(matriz, axis=0)
```

o resultado do print é:

```
[[ 57.35 100.    52.4  100.    50.    50.     0.    57.35  62.64  89.27
  100.   100.   100.    50.    50.   100.    50.   100.    50.  ]]
```

os [R's] são listas similares ao resultado final, (em Excel são calculados nas colunas de "L%" a "6º").
O problema é que ao fazer por este método (em python) perco alguns resultados (pois deveria ter 29 e não apenas os 19 apresentados), para não falar que não consigo inserir os resultados de texto, tal como exemplificado em Excel...
o calculo dos [R's] é feito assim:

```
if row['Data'] < 10: 
        n=(0.5+L/100+c1*0.5)*100
        R5.append(n)
    else:
        n=0
        R5.append(n)
```

os resultados em texto estou a tentar inserir assim:

```
if row['Data'] >= 0 and row['Teste']=='kkk':
    b2="Vistoria Recomendada"
    R8.append(b2)
```

Já me aconselharam fazer em pandas.DataFrame, mas não consigo inserir os elementos "else" e não sei se terei o mesmo problema na apresentação final de resultados...
para já tenho algo do género:

```
 a = df[(df['data'].str.contains('xy')) | (df['data'].str.contains('xx'))
   x = a[a['outro']<7]['outro']
   L = (-0.0003*x**6)
```

aqui deveria ter ainda um "else" para "a[a['outro']>=7]['outro']"...
sendo que depois tenho que fazer isto para as demais colunas e ter como resultado algo igual à coluna "Probabilidade3 %" (em Excel)...

resultado atual:

```
[list([100.0, 57.34999999999999, 62.63999999999997, 0, 100, 100, 52.40000000000031, 100.0, 0, 0, 0, 57.34999999999999, 62.63999999999997, 89.27000000000007, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 50.0, 0, 0, 100.0, 100, 0, 0, 100.0, 0, 50.0])]
```

Comment: Por favor, tenha mais cuidado ao criar uma pergunta e use títulos apenas quando forem títulos.

Comment: Qual o resultado atual? Sei que está diferente do esperado, mas o quê?

Comment: editei a pergunta